# Why don't these Composer dependencies allow upgrading to Drupal 10?

Tags: composer

I'm currently on Drupal Version 9.5.10, and I cannot update to Drupal 10 due to some depdendancy conflicts.

I updated my database, cleared cache, ran a cron. It doesn't fix.

How can I upgrade to Drupal 10 ? I am currently on Drupal 9.5.10

```
[root@vlstage22 master]# 
[root@vlstage22 master]# composer require drupal/core-recommended:10.1.1 drupal/core-composer-scaffold:10.1.1 drupal/core-project-message:10.1.1 -W --ignore-platform-reqs
Do not run Composer as root/super user! See https://getcomposer.org/root for details
Continue as root/super user [yes]? 
./composer.json has been updated
Running composer update drupal/core-recommended drupal/core-composer-scaffold drupal/core-project-message --with-all-dependencies
Loading composer repositories with package information
Info from https://repo.packagist.org: #StandWithUkraine
Updating dependencies
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Root composer.json requires drupal/core-recommended 10.1.1 -> satisfiable by drupal/core-recommended[10.1.1].
    - drupal/core-recommended 10.1.1 requires drupal/core 10.1.1 -> found drupal/core[10.1.1] but these were not loaded, likely because it conflicts with another require.


Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json and ./composer.lock to their original content.
[root@vlstage22 master]#
```

composer.json file

```
{
    "name": "drupal/recommended-project",
    "description": "Project template for Drupal 9 projects with a relocated document root",
    "type": "project",
    "license": "GPL-2.0-or-later",
    "homepage": "https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal",
    "support": {
        "docs": "https://www.drupal.org/docs/user_guide/en/index.html",
        "chat": "https://www.drupal.org/node/314178"
    },
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "composer",
            "url": "https://packages.drupal.org/8"
        }
    ],
    "require": {
        "php": "^7.3||^8.0",
        "composer/installers": "^1.9",
        "drupal/admin_toolbar": "^3.4",
        "drupal/api": "^2.0@RC",
        "drupal/auto_entitylabel": "^3.0",
        "drupal/bootstrap": "^3.29",
        "drupal/core-composer-scaffold": "^10.0",
        "drupal/core-project-message": "^10.0",
        "drupal/core-recommended": "^10.0",
        "drupal/ctools": "^4.0",
        "drupal/devel": "^5.1",
        "drupal/diff": "^1.1",
        "drupal/encrypt": "^3.1",
        "drupal/entityreference_filter": "^1.4",
        "drupal/flood_control": "^2.3",
        "drupal/fpa": "^4.0",
        "drupal/masquerade": "^2.0@RC",
        "drupal/module_filter": "^4.0",
        "drupal/pathauto": "^1.11",
        "drupal/queue_ui": "^3.1",
        "drupal/search_api": "^1.29",
        "drupal/superfish": "^1.6",
        "drupal/token": "^1.12",
        "drupal/views_bulk_operations": "^4.2",
        "drupal/watchdog_prune": "^2.3",
        "drush/drush": "^11.6",
        "php-imap/php-imap": "^2.0",
        "symfony/finder": "^6.1"
    },
    "conflict": {
        "drupal/drupal": "*"
    },
    "minimum-stability": "stable",
    "prefer-stable": true,
    "config": {
        "sort-packages": true,
        "allow-plugins": {
            "composer/installers": true,
            "drupal/core-composer-scaffold": true,
            "drupal/core-project-message": true
        }
    },
    "extra": {
        "drupal-scaffold": {
            "locations": {
                "web-root": "web/"
            }
        },
        "installer-paths": {
            "web/core": [
                "type:drupal-core"
            ],
            "web/libraries/{$name}": [
                "type:drupal-library"
            ],
            "web/modules/contrib/{$name}": [
                "type:drupal-module"
            ],
            "web/profiles/contrib/{$name}": [
                "type:drupal-profile"
            ],
            "web/themes/contrib/{$name}": [
                "type:drupal-theme"
            ],
            "drush/Commands/contrib/{$name}": [
                "type:drupal-drush"
            ],
            "web/modules/custom/{$name}": [
                "type:drupal-custom-module"
            ],
            "web/profiles/custom/{$name}": [
                "type:drupal-custom-profile"
            ],
            "web/themes/custom/{$name}": [
                "type:drupal-custom-theme"
            ]
        },
        "drupal-core-project-message": {
            "include-keys": [
                "homepage",
                "support"
            ],
            "post-create-project-cmd-message": [
                "<bg=blue;fg=white>                                                         </>",
                "<bg=blue;fg=white>  Congratulations, you’ve installed the Drupal codebase  </>",
                "<bg=blue;fg=white>  from the drupal/recommended-project template!          </>",
                "<bg=blue;fg=white>                                                         </>",
                "",
                "<bg=yellow;fg=black>Next steps</>:",
                "  * Install the site: https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/install",
                "  * Read the user guide: https://www.drupal.org/docs/user_guide/en/index.html",
                "  * Get support: https://www.drupal.org/support",
                "  * Get involved with the Drupal community:",
                "      https://www.drupal.org/getting-involved",
                "  * Remove the plugin that prints this message:",
                "      composer remove drupal/core-project-message"
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have taken this file and ran the same command. The full output is:

```
composer require drupal/core-recommended:10.1.1 drupal/core-composer-scaffold:10.1.1 drupal/core-project-message:10.1.1 -W --ignore-platform-reqs
./composer.json has been updated
Running composer update drupal/core-recommended drupal/core-composer-scaffold drupal/core-project-message --with-all-dependencies
Loading composer repositories with package information
Info from https://repo.packagist.org: #StandWithUkraine
Updating dependencies
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Root composer.json requires drupal/core-recommended 10.1.1 -> satisfiable by drupal/core-recommended[10.1.1].
    - Root composer.json requires drupal/entityreference_filter ^1.4 -> satisfiable by drupal/entityreference_filter[1.4.0].
    - drupal/entityreference_filter 1.4.0 requires drupal/core ^8 || ^9 -> satisfiable by drupal/core[8.0.0, ..., 8.9.20, 9.0.0, ..., 9.5.10].
    - You can only install one version of a package, so only one of these can be installed: drupal/core[8.0.0, ..., 8.9.20, 9.0.0, ..., 9.5.10, 10.0.0, ..., 10.1.2].
    - You can only install one version of a package, so only one of these can be installed: drupal/core[8.7.0, ..., 8.9.20, 9.0.0, ..., 9.5.10, 10.0.0, ..., 10.1.2].
    - drush/drush 11.6.0 conflicts with drupal/core 9.1.15.
    ...
    - drupal/core-recommended 10.1.1 requires drupal/core 10.1.1 -> satisfiable by drupal/core[10.1.1].
    - Root composer.json requires drush/drush ^11.6 -> satisfiable by drush/drush[11.6.0].
```

So the issue is:

```
drupal/entityreference_filter 1.4.0 requires drupal/core ^8 || ^9
```

drupal/entityreference_filter is not compatible with Drupal 10. You must remove it or use the beta version:

```
composer require drupal/core-recommended:10.1.1 drupal/core-composer-scaffold:10.1.1 drupal/core-project-message:10.1.1 'drupal/entityreference_filter:^2.0@beta'  -W --ignore-platform-reqs
```

Comment: Also I noticed your Composer command output is different than mine. You should upgrade Composer to the latest version.

Comment: Problem 1
    - Root composer.json requires drupal/core-recommended 10.1.1 -> satisfiable by drupal/core-recommended[10.1.1].
    - drupal/core-recommended 10.1.1 requires psr/log ~3.0.0 -> found psr/log[3.0.0] but these were not loaded, likely because it conflicts with another require.

Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json and ./composer.lock to their original content.

Comment: I do not know what you are trying to communicate with that comment.

Comment: i tried this

composer require drupal/core-recommended:10.1.1 drupal/core-composer-scaffold:10.1.1 drupal/core-project-message:10.1.1 'drupal/entityreference_filter:^2.0@beta'  -W --ignore-platform-reqs

Comment: but it gives this error 

Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Root composer.json requires drupal/core-recommended 10.1.1 -> satisfiable by drupal/core-recommended[10.1.1].
    - drupal/core-recommended 10.1.1 requires psr/log ~3.0.0 -> found psr/log[3.0.0] but these were not loaded, likely because it conflicts with another require.

Comment: What command gives that error? Did you change something? Did you upgrade Composer as I advised?

Comment: my Composer version 2.5.5 2023-03-21 11:50:05

Comment: this command gives that error :-     composer require drupal/core-recommended:10.1.1 drupal/core-composer-scaffold:10.1.1 drupal/core-project-message:10.1.1 'drupal/entityreference_filter:^2.0@beta' -W --ignore-platform-reqs

Comment: It does not do so for me. Consider deleting the composer.lock file. What is the PHP version?

Comment: PHP
Version
8.1.18

Comment: After deleting the composer.lock file able to migrate to drupal 10 thanx a lot for your help @cilefen

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the command you are running is `composer require...` that's incorrect you need to run composer update. Please see the docs they are very clear and easy to follow https://www.drupal.org/docs/updating-drupal/updating-drupal-core-via-composer